# How to check if a product is already on the wishlist in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, wishlist

In Magento 1.x I did it like this:

```
$_product = ...; // some product object you already have
$_productCollection = Mage::helper('wishlist')->getProductCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('sku', $_product->getSku());
if($_productCollection->count() > 0) {
    // User already has item in wishlist.
}
```

How can I achieve the same in Magento 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, we can use `\Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data` to check if a product is already on the wishlist.

```
/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper **/

$wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection()
              ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $_product->getId());
```

Remember to inject this class in your construction.

Comment: @ren it's better if you read the code from `\Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data::getWishlistItemCollection()`. And see how it works.

Comment: Please answer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281492/how-to-check-my-current-product-is-already-added-to-wishlist-magento-2

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Can i get help on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330889/57334

Answer (score 3):

> Try this code..

```
<?php
$wishlistHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data');

if($wishlistHelper->isAllow()){

$wishlistCollection = $wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection();     
foreach ($wishlistCollection as $_wishlist_item) {
   $in_wishlist = false;
   if ($_product->getId() == $_wishlist_item->getProduct()->getId()) {
       $in_wishlist = true; break;
   }
}
?>

if(!empty($_in_wishlist) && $_in_wishlist){ ?>
  <li><span class="in-wishlist"><?= __('Already in Wishlist')?></span></li>
<?php }else{ ?>
  <li><a href="<?= $wishlistHelper->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?= __('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_in_wishlist = false;
foreach ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getWishlistItemCollection() as $_wishlist_item){
    if($_product->getId() == $_wishlist_item->getProduct()->getId()){
        $_in_wishlist = true;
    }
}
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
{
    if($_in_wishlist) { ?>
        <a href="#" data-post="#" data-action="already-in-wishlist"><span class="wish-list lineheight48"><img data-alt-src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/icons/body-shop-icons_wishlist_filled.svg'); ?>" width="38" src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/icons/icon-wishlist-black.svg'); ?>' alt="Wish list"></span></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="#" data-post='<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getAddParams($_product) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span class="wish-list lineheight48"><img data-alt-src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/icons/body-shop-icons_wishlist_filled.svg'); ?>" width="38" src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/icons/icon-wishlist.svg'); ?>' alt="Wish list"></span></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php 
} else { ?> 

    <a href="#" data-post='<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getAddParams($_product) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span class="wish-list lineheight48"><img data-alt-src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/icons/body-shop-icons_wishlist_filled.svg'); ?>" width="38" src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/icons/icon-wishlist.svg'); ?>' alt="Wish list"></span></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In other way you can  get wishlist items collection.

Use  factory **`Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory`** for getting *wishlist product collection*

Use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface to get it in your constructor

and filter  that by `addCustomerIdFilter($customerId)`

```
protected $_currentUserWishlistCollectionFactory ;
protected $_Customersession;
private $productRepository;     
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory $currentUserWishlistCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $Customersession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository

    ) {
    ....
    $this->_Customersession = $Customersession;
$this->_currentUserWishlistCollectionFactory = $currentUserWishlistCollectionFactory;
$this->productRepository = $productRepository;
....

    }

public function getcurrentUserWishlistItems(){
    $productId  = false;
    $collection = $this->_currentUserWishlistCollectionFactory->create();
$product = $this->loadMyProduct($_product->getSku());
$productId= $product->getId();
    $collection->addCustomerIdFilter($this->_Customersession->getCustomerId());
$collection->addFieldToFilter('product)_id',$productId  );
    return $collection;

}

public function loadMyProduct($sku)
{
    return $this->productRepository->get($sku);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was searching for quick answer.

Comment: ah.. you already got from Khoa TruongDinh

Comment: @AmitBera can i get help on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330889/57334

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check if a product is already on the wishlist in Magento2:

```
<?php

    //Checking User logedin or not          
    $objectManager       = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $context             = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
    $isLoggedIn          = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    $customerSession     = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
      //getting customer ID
      $id =  $customerSession->getCustomerID();
    }

    //Getting wishlist products Collections  Related to Customers
    $wishlist            = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist');
    $wishlist_collection = $wishlist->loadByCustomerId( $id , true)->getItemCollection();
    $_in_wishlist        = "false";
    foreach ($wishlist_collection as $wishlist_product):
      if($_product->getId() == $wishlist_product->getProduct()->getId()){
        $_in_wishlist = "true";
        break;
      }
      endforeach;
      if($_in_wishlist == "true"): ?>
        <div class="addtowishlist added"  style="font-family: Raleway"><span>Already Added to Wishlist:</span><div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : '' ?>>
        <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
          <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
             </div>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
          <div class="addtowishlist"  style="font-family: Raleway"><span>Add to Wishlist:</span><div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : '' ?>>
          <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
            <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
             </div>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```