# How to prevent adding same item into wish list twice in magento 2.1.9

Tags: wishlist, sku, magento-2.1.9, items

I need to prevent users adding same item into user wish list. I could find an answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152913/how-to-check-if-a-product-is-already-on-the-wishlist-in-magento-2/152918#152918) .But i'm not able to implement it. please help me with the implimentation.