# Show Wishlist icon as selected when clicked

Tags: magento2

I need to show the icon as selected (may be color change) when user add a product to wishlist.
I've searched and tried the solution here [How to check if a product is already on the wishlist in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152913/how-to-check-if-a-product-is-already-on-the-wishlist-in-magento-2)
but not clear where to add this code.
Please guide me in the correct direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you upload any screenshot how it should look?

Comment: Here you got how to check in an item is in the wishlist: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152913/how-to-check-if-a-product-is-already-on-the-wishlist-in-magento-2

Comment: @GosuPrzmak if you notice, the link I shared is the same which you mentioned.

Comment: @SukumarGorai Can't upload any image right now, but you may think as a grey heart image for the normal state, and when clicked (item added to wishlist) the heart image will be replace with a colored one.

Answer (score 4):

You  have to  create a custom controller to provide wishlist data of current user. Using ajax call I got the data from this controller which gives refreshed wishlist data and not cached one.
Controller code :

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Wishlist extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->wishlistHelper = $wishlistHelper;
            $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $data = $this->wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection()->getData();

        return $result->setData(['status' => 200, 'items' => $data]);
    }
}
```

Aslo add following code in list.phtml

```
<script>
require(['jquery'], function($){
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalogchanges/index/wishlist') ?>',
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var wislistAddesCheckData = data;
            var itemLenth = wislistAddesCheckData.items.length;
            for(i=0;i<itemLenth; i++){
                var wislistAddedProductId = wislistAddesCheckData.items[i].product_id;
                $(".product-id"+wislistAddedProductId).addClass('in-wishlist');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you pls guide me on how to implement in my custom theme?

Comment: Can i get any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330889/57334

Answer (score 1):

Here you got how to check if the product is in your wishlist:

[How to check if a product is already on the wishlist in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152913/how-to-check-if-a-product-is-already-on-the-wishlist-in-magento-2)

As for second part of your question you would need to specify where you would like it to be ? catalog_category? catalog_search ? product page ?

I believe if you search in your project for phrase: "Add to Wish List" you will find the spot where to add the code you need ;)