# How to Check my Current Product is Already added to Wishlist Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, products, wishlist

```
<?php 
 echo "<pre>";    
 print_r($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getWishlistItemCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $_product->getId())->count());
 die();
 ?>
```

I am using this Query to get wish list added product Count but it returns always '0', my current product is already added into wish list !! How to solve this issue?

> vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml

Currently, I am testing with 'wishlist.phtml' vendor file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use this below code :

```
protected $wishlist;
protected $registry;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
    $this->registry = $registry;
    ...
}

public function yourFunction(){
    $customer_id = 1;
    $wishlist_collection = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customer_id, true)->getItemCollection();
    $current_product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    foreach ($wishlist_collection as $item) {
        if($current_product->getId() == $item->getProduct()->getId())
        {
            // current item added in wishlist
        } else {
            // current item not added in wishlist
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

---

**Object Manager Method :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customer_id = $session->getCustomer()->getId(); 


$wishlist_collection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist')->loadByCustomerId($customer_id, true)->getItemCollection();
$current_product =  $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
foreach ($wishlist_collection as $item) {
    if($current_product->getId() == $item->getProduct()->getId())
    {
        // current item added in wishlist
    } else {
        // current item not added in wishlist
    }
}
```

Comment: can i use this wishlist.phtml  file ?

Comment: You want to add code in core file?

Comment: no, i need custom module and file wishlist.phtml '' app/code/vendor/module/templates/catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml

Comment: Do you have helper or block file of your custom module?

Comment: not now, currently i'm just testing in vendor file then it works l'll create

Comment: You can use this code by object manager method

Comment: Okay ,thank you for your quick response

Comment: Check my updated answer. If this answer is helpful for you, then please accept and upvote answer. So, it will helpful for other developer also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95961/discussion-between-shafeel-sha-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: @RohanHapani Can i get help on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330889/57334 thanks