# Magento2: Remove products from wishlist if it is already added to wishlist in Product detail page after clicking wishlist icon?

Tags: magento2, product, wishlist

I want to remove products from wishlist if it is already added to wishlist in Product detail page after clicking wishlist icon in magento2.3.0?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to remove wishlist item first if that already exist instead of changing item's QTY right ?

Comment: Yes your are right.

Comment: Okay let me check and ping you.

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152918/9169) to verify if item is already in wishlist. If it is present in wishlist, you can use below code to remove the item from wishlist:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\General\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class RemoveFromWishlist extends Action {
    protected $wishlist;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        if(!$customerId) {
           $jsonData = ['result' => ['status' => 200, 'message' => 'Customer not logged in.']]; 
            $result = $this->jsonFactory->create()->setData($jsonData);
            return $result;
        }

        $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productId');

        $wish = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
        $items = $wish->getItemCollection();

        /** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $item */
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) {

                $item->delete();
                $wish->save();
            }
        }
        $jsonData = ['result' => ['status' => 200, 'message' => 'Removed from wishlist']];
        $result = $this->jsonFactory->create()->setData($jsonData);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know where to apply this code.

Comment: In the pdp template where wishlist code is present, check if item is already in wishlist. If present, send a ajax request to custom controller which will remove item from wishlist. Custom controller code is shared above.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `events.xml` file in your custom module here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_add">
        <observer name="wishlist_index_add_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\RemoveWishlistItemBeforeAdd" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now you need to create one Observer file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/RemoveWishlistItemBeforeAdd.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class RemoveWishlistItemBeforeAdd implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerSession;

    protected $wishlist;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        $currentProductId = $observer->getRequest()->getParam('product');

        if($customerId){
            $currentCustomerWishlist = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
            $wishlistItems = $currentCustomerWishlist->getItemCollection();

            foreach ($wishlistItems as $wishlistItem) {
                if ($wishlistItem->getProductId() == $currentProductId) {
                    $wishlistItem->delete();
                }
            }
        }

        return $observer;
    }  
}
```

You can download this module as well.. [Download](https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/sk-remove-wishlist-item-before-add)

Hope this will help!

Comment: let me know if it helps.

Comment: I have implemented this code not working..

Comment: Can you please download my module and install that and check once ?

Comment: I have applied your downloaded module only..

Comment: Can you please use echo die in observer and then check my observer file is calling when you click on add to wishlist button ?

Comment: Is the code working for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101167/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-amy).

Comment: @KishanSavaliya can i get any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330865/57334

Comment: @KishanSavaliya Can u pls help regard related post https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/333645/57334